# iOS 8 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController search bar keyboard resign

Tags: ios, searchbar, abpeoplepickerview

I want to resign the search bar keyboard in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController programmatically. In iOS 7 I use 
    [self.peoplePicker.searchDisplayController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
to resign the keyboard and it works fine. But in iOS 8 it doesn't work any more.
Thanks for any advice.